# How to check if IMAPFolder is hidden?

Tags: jakarta-mail

How may I check if a `javax.mail.Folder` or `com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder` object in JavaMail API represents a hidden folder?

Answer (score 0):

There's no universal notion of "hidden folder".

If your IMAP server is using UNIX files, you can check that the folder/file name starts with a dot.

What sort of IMAP server are you using?  Do you have existing folders that are "hidden"?

Comment: I am using exchange server as an IMAP server. Yes, I do have a folder which seems hidden in each mailbox, the folder name is 'Journal'. I am able to identify hidden folders using Exchange Web Services API, however I am looking to its equivalent in IMAP.

Comment: There's definitely no standard IMAP way to do this, but possibly there's a vendor-specific flag that shows up in th LIST response for the folder.

Comment: I see, I wish it would be provided one day in IMAP. My application deals with different kind of mail servers and I have not found a way so far in any server to identify the hidden folders.